# High memory usage on Android Application

Tags: java, android

I have a little application, this application has seven activities, basically 6 are layouts with images and one is a MapActivity, among of 5 layouts one has a ArrayList of a internal class and each time that I use my application the memory grows to 50mb, 70mb, 111mb... I tried to call Garbage Collector but I didn't receive the expected result.

```
public class GC 
{    
    public static final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    public static void Free()
    {
        runtime.gc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: 
[Avoid memory leaks on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567647/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android)

1. Make sure you are properly closing your other activities (this.finish).
2. You need to remove the callbacks to images otherwise you will leak memory.

   ```
   private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
   if (view.getBackground() != null) {
       view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
   }
   if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
       for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
           unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
       }
       ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
   }
   ```

Call it with the view's root (i.e. unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.xml_layout_root));

Comment: I implemented your solution but I'm still getting over memory! I am crazy, because I don't know how can I clean memory on android application.